# Adding wmode="opaque" to embed with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to add wmode="opaque" to the  that contains my YouTube video, so I do jQuery('embed').attr('wmode', 'opaque'), but nothing is added, what do I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

your code seems to be fine :

```
$("embed").attr("wmode","opaque");
```

but you should also add :

`<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />` to the object element ....

so maybe you miss it .

also try to load the script after a click of a button

your flash object might be initialize AFTER you set the wmode....

so try to put the command of adding the wmode as a click on button

and see if it is the problem

Comment: Use opaque, not transparent. Transparent is more CPU intensive.

Comment: Still doesn't add any attribute to the embed object, even if the code is executed only on a click. Does the fact that my YouTube video is contained in an iframe have something to do with my issue ?

Comment: @drake035 the iframe is yours ?

Comment: @Royi Namir : yes, on youtube.com I just clicked on Share > Embed, then copied the <iframe ..> code.